# Hover effect for settings dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, visibility

When I mouse over the red settings-icon, I want the drop down menu to appear. And when I mouse off the settings-icon or dropdown-menu, it goes back to just the settings icon.

I tried using

visibility: hidden;
visibility: visible;

I can't seem to figure it out.

**http://jsbin.com/OmEfEGu/2/edit**

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">

<div class="check-icon"></div>
<li>Mark as Answered</li>

<div class="trash-icon"></div>
<li>Delete Questions</li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.settings-icon {
position: relative;
width: 18px;
height: 20px;
background-color: red;
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid #8b9399;
border-left: 1px solid #8b9399;
border-right: 1px solid #8b9399;

}

.dropdown-menu {
border: 1px solid #8b9399;
background-color: #ffffff;
float: right;
width: 140px;
height: 50px;
margin-right: -20px;
margin-top: 20px;
list-style: none;
font-size: 13px;
}

.settings-icon:hover .dropdown-menu {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to write some script for this. And you can't use li elements without an enclosing ul or ol.

Comment: Oh my god, that markup :c